# npm @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts package not found

Tags: npm, npm-install, font-awesome-5

I am trying to install  @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts through npm. I have set their repository into my npm config

```
; userconfig C:\Users\user10\.npmrc
@fortawesome:registry = "https://npm.fontawesome.com/MY-PRO-KEY"
```

When I run `npm install` I get:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts@5.2.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
```

If I use `npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro` it successfully installs the package.

why when I use `npm install` it does not find the package?

Comment: Because @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro is not the same as @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts

Comment: ah you are right. Package name was changed. My bad.